# How To Calculate Fluorescent To Incandescent Wattage?

Tags: watts, compact-fluorescent-lamp, incandescent

This is simple mathematical question but I cannot figure it out:

Compact fluorescent lamps consume 75% less wattage and still deliver equal power of incandescent lamp. If 15W compact fluorescent lamp which consumes 75% less wattage, delivers same result as 60W incandescent lamp then how much wattage of incandescent lamp delivers 9W compact fluorescent lamp?

Please tell me calculation. Thanks.

Comment: Homework? I don't see the electronics question either.

Comment: Would this be a better fit for mathematics stackexchange maybe?

Comment: @Brian: Not homework for anyone old enough to be allowed here.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - Have you looked at the front page of [math.se] or [Mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/) recently? This would not be a [good homework question there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer Actually, yes, but what caused my suggestion was the official stance of Math that they accept questions for any educational level. On the other hand Mathoverflow is a no go since they are for math research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is off topic, but it's right out of 7th grade arthmetic and easy to answer, so I'll just do it:

*If johnny leaves his apples on the table and Suzy always takes 3/4 of them at noon, then how many apples did Johnny start with if Suzy left 9 of them?*

F = I - (75% I)
F = 25% I
F = .25 I

I = F / .25
I = 4 F

Therefore according to your 75% figure, a 9W fluorescent would put out as much light as a 36W incandescent.

Comment: Thanks. What 75% in brackets does with I? Multiplies or divides?

Comment: @Boris: You mean the "75% I" in the parenthesis?  In general when a mathematical operator is left out, it is understood to be multiplication.  Therefore (75% I) = 75% * I = .75 * I

Answer (score 3):

I'll not go into detailed description why this is not a good way to compare the light sources. Basically the only real way to be sure is to read the specification of the 9 W CFL or to do measurements yourself.

Anyway, to answer the question here we have a basic elementary-school lever proportion.

If we assume that both CFLs are of same efficiency and so on (and we can't safely do that), we can say that:

\$P_{1I}= 60 \mbox{ } W\$
\$P_{1CFL}=15 \mbox{ } W\$
\$P_{2I}=X\mbox{ }W\$
\$P_{2CFL}= 9 \mbox{ }W\$

We may also dare to claim that:
\$P_{1I}:P_{1CFL}=P_{2I}:P_{2CFL}\$
From that, we can calculate that:
\$P_{2I}=\frac{P_{1I}P_{2CFL}}{P_{1CFL}}\$
The final result would be that \$P_{2I}= 36 \mbox{ }W\$

Comment: Ha, beat you to the answer by 2 seconds!

Comment: @Olin Lathrop But MINE is better! :)